# Do I need to use a factory in order to inject a simple object in Jersey?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

As of right now in order to inject an object of type Foo into Bar I do the following.

**Class to be injected into:**

```
class Bar {
    @Inject
    Foo field;

    public Foo getField() { return field; }
}
```

**Code implementing Factory:**

```
public class Foo implements Factory<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo provide() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(Foo f) {
    }
}
```

**Code in Main Configuration:**

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
                .packages("com.example")
                .register(
                        new AbstractBinder() {
                            @Override
                            protected void configure() {
                                bindFactory(new FooFactory()).to(Foo.class).in(Singleton.class);
                            }
                        })
```

My question is... In Jersey 2.0 which uses hk2 for dependency injection is there anyway to inject an object without creating a factory class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use an `AbstractBinder` for injection binding without a `Factory` or an `InjectionResolver`.

```
    register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Foo.class).to(Foo.class);
            bind(Bar.class).to(Bar.class);
        }
    });
```

In this case the classes Foo and Bar have empty constructors.

```
public class Bar {
    @Inject
    Foo field;
    public Foo getField() { return field; }
}

public class Foo {}
```

Now you can inject Bar into a resource or other hk2 beans.

Comment: What if the class had a constructor with parameters?  Would all those parameters need @Inject as well?

Comment: not possible, you can use @Inject on fields only, or you bind the instance this way: bind(new Bar("test")).to(Bar.class);

Comment: in general, for more complex injection requirements (e.g. assisted injection) you have to use the InjectionResolver or Factories.

Comment: Well, you can use @Inject on a constructor as well as a method.  If you do then all the parameters of the constructor must also be hk2 services that can be resolved at the time hk2 is trying to construct the object

Comment: ah yes, sure ... `@Inject public AResource(Hk2Bean1 a, Hk2Bean2 b) {...}` is possible